# How to show modal dialog or popup of FMElfinderBundle integrated with TrsteelCkeditorBundle?

Tags: symfony, modal-dialog, ckeditor, elfinder

I want to use FMElfinderBundle on modal dialog. Now when i click on Browse server botton on Ckeditor new tab on my browser opened and I should work on it to upload image or select one image that is existing on server directory.

Answer (score 0):

As i know current version of CKEditor doesn't support modal/iframe based calls, you can use TinyMCE, that opens filebrowser in iframe.